# Parse Server aggregate using match on date column

Tags: mongodb, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm using `parse-server` version 2.7.4 with `parse` (the JavaScript interface) version 1.11.1. I'm trying to execute an `aggregate` query using `match` on a date column. Here's what my pipeline looks like:

```
[
  {
    match: {
      '_created_at': new Date('2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    }
  }
]
```

I most definitely have records in the database greater than that date, yet this query returns me zero records in JavaScript. However, if I run it in the Mongo shell, I get documents returned. Here is what I execute in the Mongo shell:

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      '_created_at': ISODate('2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    }
  }
]
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `parse` JavaScript API or does it not support `match` aggregation on date columns? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like this is a documented issue: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4678